# showing errorn RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions. in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a custom Color picker with showDialog but its showing following error

RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

i am using a listview in content of showDialog property..

```
CupertinoButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: (){
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Select Color'),
                content: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0,right: 8,top: 4,bottom: 4),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)
                  ),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: colorlist.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child: CupertinoButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            onPressed: () {
                              selectedColor=colorlist[index];
                              setState(() {
                              });
                            },
                            child: ColorDotWidget(
                              color: colorlist[index],
                              isSelected: colorlist[index]==selectedColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                actions: [TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Done'))],

              );
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.blue
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `width` to the `Container` that is your `AlertDialog`'s `content`. Then re-run the code (don't just hotstart).